# Can't get eclipse kepler to deploy dependency projects of dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I've recently upgraded from Eclipse Juno to Kepler, and have imported some old projects into a new workspace, but unfortunately I cannot get publishing of one of my web projects to work.  It has dependencies on a couple of other projects in the same workspace, and these projects are listed in the 'deployment assembly' tab with entries like

```
Source                 Deploy Path
/eventserver           WEB-INF/lib
```

that I have added using the 'Add/Project' option (I'm pretty sure I've previously used 'Add/Entries from Classpath' but that option does not list the projects, so I don't know what's going on).  But neither the projects' code nor their dependencies are being deployed to WEB-INF/lib when I publish the main project.  Also, I have the following warning showing up:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Projects must be referenced by an EAR or a WAR to use classpath publish/export dependencies whose runtime path (../) maps into the parent component.    eventserver     P/eventserver   Classpath Dependency Validator Message
```

which I only used to get if I didn't have a main project that referred to the utility project.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Create an EAR project using this link:

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/j2ee/scenarios/application_creation_tutorial.html

After creation, try to Add the Project in server entry.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why creating an EAR project would help?  I already have a WAR project with dependencies on the modules in question, but the dependencies aren't being picked up during publishing.  I really would rather not add a fourth project to what's already quite a complex project structure...

Comment: Have you checked the Project Facets? Some WAR configuration could be missing.

Comment: I haven't.  Is there anything specific you think I should be looking for?

Comment: Eclipse will recognize your WAR correctly only if your Facets configurations have the correct entries. The EAR Project resolves this for you. I still think the EAR creation is relevant.